# TinkerBoard 2s Serial Connection UART0

Tags: uart, tty, serial-communication, tinker

i am trying to connect my PC and my TinkerBoard 2s via UART0.

I found this forum post:
https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=149981

which relates to this on page 11:
https://tinker-board.asus.com/images/doc/download/Tinker_Edge_R_Getting_Started.pdf

So what i already did is:
in /dev/config.txt

```
    "intf:fiq_debugger=on" → "intf:fiq_debugger=off"
    "#intf:uart0=off"      → "intf:uart0=on"
    "overlay="             → "overlay=console-uart0-overlay"
```

My Question now:
where do i have to put

```
    uart1 = Serial("/dev/ttyS0=",115200)
    uart3 = Serial("/dev/ttyS4=",9600)
```

I put it at the end of config.txt, but when i "cat /dev/ttyS0" on TinkerBoard and connect via PUTTY on COM3 and 115200, nothing happens...

Do i have to put it in the same file (config.txt)? or into the cmdline.txt?
Did i forgot something? Do I have to change "overlay=" -> "overlay=console-uart0-overlay"?

(I dont care if i will get to console or sending chars for now)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put those lines in your Python code.